# How to insert or update a record using fieldset without using standard save method?

Tags: fieldsets

I want to write code for inserting and updating record using fieldset, but i don't know how to map the fields(from fieldset) to my controller. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below to get the field set name and fields in your controller.

```
public static List<schema.fieldsetmember> getFields(String objectName, String fieldSetName) {  
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
    Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(objectName);
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();            
    Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);        
    System.debug('-----------fieldSetObj.getFields()--------'+fieldSetObj.getFields());
    return fieldSetObj.getFields(); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks!
Ruchika Saxena

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however  i guess this code is for retrieving fields from fieldset for particular object.  What i want to do is to take the input from user in the fields(which are retrieved using fieldset ) and write the code for inserting record in my controller.